# SubMenus No Se visualiza en bootstrap con angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular7

Se esta haciendo un menú con Bootstrap, y se requiere hacer un submenu pero NO se están visualizando los item del submenu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el Código html lo he revisado varias veces pero no encuentro que pudiera estar fallando, no se si hace falta algo en CSS

```css
/*el css del component nav-menu.component.css*/

.navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
}

/* rotate caret on hover */
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover:after {
    text-decoration: underline;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Menu Productos -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand pb-2" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> Productos <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--dark">

    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]='["/ConsoProductos"]'>
        <i class="fa fa-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Consolidado
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu--dark">
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]='["/RegistroProductos"]'>
         Registro de Productos
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li >
          <a class="dropdown-item" >
             Generación Nuevo Conocimiento
          </a>
        </li>
        
        <li >
          <a class="dropdown-item">
             Desarrollo Tecnológico e Innovación
          </a>
        </li>
        <li >
          <a class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fa fa-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Apropiación Social del Conocimiento
          </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</li>

<!-- Fin Menu productos -->
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Fin Menu productos -->
```

Debería de sacarme un menu y submenu como se indica en esta imagen...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**UPDATE**

El código del componente del nav-bar

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 declare let $: any;

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-nav-menu',
 templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
 })

 export class NavMenuComponent {
  isExpanded = false;

 collapse() {
  this.isExpanded = false;
 }

 toggle() {
  this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
 }

 ngOnInit() {
  const altura = $('.navbar').offset().top;

  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
     $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
   } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
   }
  });

    $('.nav-principal > li.dropdown').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('open');

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
   });
 });

 $('.modal-content').resizable({
   //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
   minHeight: 300,
   minWidth: 300
  });
  $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

$('#ModalAgregar').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
    'max-height': '300%'
  });
 });
}
}
```

No he podido encontrar el error porque no se visualiza los item del submenu!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo faltaba agregar algo de esilo a las etiquetas .dropdown-menu>li:hover ul.dropdown-menu

```
.dropdown-menu>li:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 100%;
 }
```